# Does the series, ${1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}},\frac{3}{8},\frac{8}{15},...$ has any famous relation to any problem/field or a definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, natural-numbers

A friend of mine showed me this series and wanted me to find a $p(n)$ for this. Did it, but this series looks like something of a pre-established one. I'm not very much advanced into math, so does this series has some recognition?

I'll probably edit this question on how he derived this series or on what basis, but for the meantime this is what I've got.

So by the looks of it; (thanks to @PeterForeman)

$$p(n) = \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}$$

Comment: There is a way you can get this and there's a pattern. I'm also currently asking my friend on this, so will get back to that soon

Comment: I don't recognize the pattern at sight., and without context it is very difficult if not *impossible* to guess correctly.  There are after all uncountably infinitely many rational sequences which begin with the terms you used.  I would *guess* that if your sequence were $p(n)$, then it would be $a(n)/a(n+1)$ where $a(n)$ begins $1,1,2,3,8,15,\dots$ (*i.e. the numerator of a term is the same as the denominator of the previous term*)., but which sequence $a(n)$ is specifically is [unclear](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C8%2C15&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: @JMoravitz, as you can see the denominator of $p(n)$ will be the numerator of $p(n+1)$

Comment: that is *evidenced* by what we have seen so far, but it is by no means *proven*.

Comment: SO what comes after $\frac 8{15}$?  Is it $\frac {15}{32,768}$?  That would follow the pattern following $\frac ab\to \frac b{2^b}$ if $b$ is odd and $\frac ab \to \frac b{2*b -1}$ if $b$ is even.  But just because that is *a* pattern that works that doesn't mean it is the *intended* pattern.  There are an infinite possible patterns.  SO tradition says the pattern in the "simplest" and "most obvious" pattern.  But I don't see that there is a simplest or most obvious.  The one desribed is this one in *my* opinion that is simplest but it almost certainly is not the intended.

Comment: @fleablood I think the pattern is $$p(n) = \frac{denominator of p(n-1)}{numerator of p(n-1) * n}$$

Comment: It *could* be.  But there is no reason to think it *is*.  It could also be $p(n) = \frac {denominaotor of p(n-1)}{2^{denominator of p(n-1)}\text{ if it is odd}or 2(denominator of p(n-1))-1 \text{if it is even}}$.  There is no way to tell if it is one or another.

Comment: Although I imagine Peter foreman's guess is probably the intended answer.  But I maintain that this is still an UNANSWERABLE question.  It is not possible to determine infinite patterns from a finite number of terms.  *Ever*.  And I wish to the everloving Cthulhuu that *stupid* math texts and stupid text questions would *stop* asking these meaningless *impossible* questions.  They are simply *wrong*.  Not merely innocently wrong but fundamentally and conceptually wrong.

Comment: Actually, did the friend who showed you this imply that $p(n)$ was a polynomial?  (That's what the symbol $p(n)$ usually means).  If so neither Peter's nor my interpretation is a a polynomial.  Coming up with a fourth degree polynomial where $p(x)= ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ and $p(0)= e = 1$ and $p(1) =a+b+c+d+e=\frac 12$ and $p(2)= 16a+8b+4c+2d+e=\frac 23$ and $p(3)=81a+27b+9c+3d+e=\frac 38$ and $p(4)=256a+64b+16c+4d+3=\frac {8}{15}$ is fairly mechanical.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like
$$\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}\\
&=\frac{n\cdot(n-2)\cdots(1\text{ or }2)}{(n+1)\cdot(n-1)\cdots(2\text{ or }1)}\\
\end{align}$$
where I use $n!!$ to denote the [double factorial](https://oeis.org/A006882). But then again it could be an arbitrary polynomial without an infinite number terms.

Comment: Or equivalently $a_{2k-1}=\binom{2k}{k}\Big/4^k$, $a_{2k-2}=4^k\Big/\left[2k\binom{2k}{k}\right]$ if one wants to get rid of double factorials.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, did the friend who showed you this imply that $p(n)$ was a polynomial?  (That's what the symbol $p(n)$ usually means).  If so neither Peter's nor my interpretation is a a polynomial.  Coming up with a fourth degree polynomial where $p(x)= ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ and $p(0)= e = 1$ and $p(1) =a+b+c+d+e=\frac 12$ and $p(2)= 16a+8b+4c+2d+e=\frac 23$ and $p(3)=81a+27b+9c+3d+e=\frac 38$ and $p(4)=256a+64b+16c+4d+e=\frac {8}{15}$ is fairly mechanical.

$e = 1$

$a+b+c+d+e=\frac 12$ so $a+b+c+d=-\frac 12$

$16a+8b+4c+2d+e=\frac 23$ so $16a+8b+4c+2d = -\frac 13$ so $8a+4b+2c+d=-\frac 16$ so $7a+3b+c=\frac 23$.

$81a+27b+9c+3d+e=\frac 38$ so $81a+27b+9c+3d=-\frac 58$ so $27a+9b+3c+d = -\frac 5{24}$ so $26a+8b+2c=\frac 7{24}$ so $13a+4b + c=\frac 7{48}$ and $6a+b=-\frac {25}{48}$.

And $256a+64b+16c+4d+e=\frac {8}{15}$ so $256a + 64b + 16c + 4d = -\frac 7{15}. So $64a + 16b + 4c +d = -\frac 7{60}$.  So $63a+15b+3c=\frac {23}{30}$ and $(63-3*7)a + (15-3*3)b=42a+6b =\frac {23}{30} -2= -\frac {37}{30}$.  So $7a + b=-\frac{37}{210}$.

So $a = -\frac{37}{210}+\frac {25}{48}=\frac {-37*8 + 25*35}{1680}=\frac {579}{1680}$

$b = -\frac{37}{210}-7*\frac {579}{1680} =-\frac {25}{48}-6*\frac {579}{1680}= -\frac{37}{210} -\frac{579}{240} = -\frac{25}{48}-\frac {579}{280}=-\frac{37*8}{210*8}-\frac{579*7}{1680}= -\frac{25*35}{1680}-\frac{579*6}{1680}=-\frac{4349}{1680}$.

$c = \frac 23 - 7*\frac {579}{1680}+ 3*\frac{4349}{1680}=\frac{1120}{1680}+\frac{8994}{1680}=\frac {10114}{1680}$.

And $d = -\frac 12 - a -b-c = \frac {-840 -579+4349-10114}{1680}= -\frac{7184}{1680}$.

So $p(n) = \frac {579}{1680}x^4 -\frac{4349}{1680}x^3 + \frac {10114}{1680}x^2 -\frac{7184}{1680}x + 1$ will give the same values.

In which case the next term is $\frac{579*625-4349*125 + 10114*25-7184*5}{1680} + 1 = \frac{35180}{1680} + 1= \frac {1843}{84}$.

====

Peter Foreman says it looks like $a_n = \frac {n!!}{(n+1)!!}$ so that $a_5$ would be $\frac{15}{24}$.  And $a_6$ would be $\frac {24}{75}$

I say it looks like $\frac{a_{2n}}{b_{2n}} = \frac {b_{2n-1}}{2*b_{2n-1}-1}$ and $\frac {a_{2n+1}}{b+{2n+1}} = \frac {b_{2n}}{2^{b_{2n}}}$ so that $a_5$ would be $\frac {15}{32,278}$.  And $a_6$ would be $\frac {32,278}{65,535}$

Which one is correct?  Which one is better?

Well, there is *utterly* no reason or method to prefer one over the other without more information.  I'd say this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Although I did say the sequence could be represented by an arbitrary polynomial. As to say that any pattern you want could be found.

Comment: That's true.  You did say that.